# Sharing tabs between separate instances of Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

Is there a way for Firefox to beam links/tabs from computer to computer? Say I have Firefox open on a laptop, and I want to beam a link or tab to another computer. Is there a way to do this already in Firefox?

I have something called Tab Session Manager which saves the tabs that I have open, but this is only locally and doesn't transfer the data between computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck.  You don't need an extension, that's actually a new feature in Firefox.

Set up syncing.  You can access that from `Edit | Preferences | Firefox Account`.  Pick which items, if any, you want to routinely sync between devices.  Sync is the mechanism for the new feature.

Once it's set up, right-click on a tab you want to share and there is an option, `Send Tab to Device`.  BTW, you can also access that from the three-horizontal-dot icon on the right side of the URL entry window.  You can pick any individual devices or all of them (these are the other devices on which you have also set up syncing).

The tab will show up in the Firefox session on that device (almost immediately if there is an open session, or the next time you open Firefox there).

Comment: Does this only work if both of the devices to which I want to transfer tabs to are active and online on Firefox? Say a laptop wants to beam a tab to a desktop but the desktop isn't turned on and on Firefox. Would this still beam it there for when the desktop does get turned on and Firefox is open?

Comment: @Qhucy, correct, that's what I described in the answer.  Mozilla's server keeps track of the status of everything.  In the case you describe, when you eventually turn on your desktop and start Firefox, Firefox will sync with Mozilla's server and the tab will show up.  The way sync works is that if you make any change in Firefox that gets synced (like bookmark a link and you have chosen to sync bookmarks), Firefox immediately sends the information to the server.  While Firefox is open (and syncing is active; i.e., you haven't disabled it), (cont'd)

Comment: it checks frequently to see if there is anything waiting for it on the server (kind of like your email client checking periodically for new messages).  So if Firefox is open on the desktop at the time you send the tab, it will quickly be displayed there.  If the desktop is shut down, the tab will wait on the server until Firefox is open and then sync.  If you have a lot of devices, give them each a recognizable name when you set up syncing on that computer so the destination devices will be easy to recognize when you select where to send the tab.